# Pandas how to select a range of columns using .filter()

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation

Im sorry if this is way too basic, but would anyone be able to share how to select ranges of columns with Pandas' **.filter()** function:
Im looking to select a range of sequential columns - from 'professional' through to 'production'. 
below is my effort - I also tried splitting into 2 lists

```
counties.\
   filter(['state', 'county', 'population', 'professional':'production']).\
   sort_values('service', ascending = False).\
   head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it filter only lists.

So here is possible select values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and join to list:

```
c = counties.loc[:, 'professional':'production'].columns.tolist()

df = (counties.filter(['state', 'county', 'population'] + c)
              .sort_values('service', ascending = False)
              .head())
```